# UITableView and SearchBarController view iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My tableview is in this user interface:

[image]

But when I start search the view gets changed as :

[image]

I want that when user starts search the view should be the same as I have used headers for different fields, like headers should be there and searched data should be shown under the same headers at its place?

Is it possible?

I am using this code:

In viewDidLoad:

```
// create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.
//filteredListItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[listItems count]];
filteredListItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.listVehicles count]];

// restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
if (self.savedSearchTerm){
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

    self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
}

[listTable reloadData];
```

Then another method:

> -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

```
self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];}
```

In searchbar methods:

```
//search bar implementation
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{        
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

self.filteredListItems = [self.listVehicles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];    
return YES;}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
[self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
return YES;}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish... please try to explain again in different words

Comment: see the difference before search and after search, before search you can see there are headers A, B, C and while after search that view gets hide and simple table comes up. I just want to have the same view with headers while searching or when the search is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement UISearchBar **without(!!!)** the SearchDisplayController. Go to your xib file, if you search for "search bar" in the right tab you will get 2 result. you should icorporate to your project only the searchBar.

another solution, just return NO to:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller    shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];    
return YES;}
```

Comment: I have tried your another solution, in which you suggested to return NO; but the problem is still there

Comment: hey Oded Regev! I have got the answer for my question, you can check it here, it might help you also, @gerry3 has given very good answer and described the issue in few words, check it ---
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922456/searchbar-is-not-working-iphone-xcode-4-2