# Searchbar is not working iPhone Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I am using this code for search bar, but it is not showing any results.

in viewdidload method:

```
 filteredListitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:listVehicles];
```

searchbar methods:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    [filteredListitems removeAllObjects];
    [filteredListitems addObjectsFromArray:listVehicles];
}else {

    [filteredListitems removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString * string in listVehicles) {
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredListitems addObject:string];
        }
    }
}    
[listTable reloadData];}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {

[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and code for each cell is:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {

        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {

            cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
        }
    }

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
    pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
    [pressRecongnizer release];

}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

    [[cell ignition] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignition.png"]];
    [[cell direction] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"south.png"]];
    NSString *cellValue = [filteredListitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.licPlate.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

}

I have tried search bar with display controller, it was working fine but the issue was that it was showing its own table view for the filtered search results, while I am using custom cell to show different columns in table like this:

[image]

I want the same view as above while searching or after search is done

while after search I get this view

[image]

See the difference between the tableviews, as in search headers get disappear, so someone suggested me to use only seachbar without display controllers.

Please guide me so that I would resolve this issue

Comment: NSLog your array filteredListitems in if statement.

Comment: checked, search button is not working and filteredListItems array showing all the items of listVehicles

Comment: how you add search bar in view?

Comment: by drag and drop from objects library

Comment: it's a search bar or searchViewController ? and had you given reference?

Comment: its a search bar not a search view controller, as I have mentioned that previously I was using serachbarcontroller but I was getting the view issue for which I pasted the screenshots, now I am using the search bar only

Comment: had you given delegate of UIsearchbar?

Comment: try to debug using breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a Search Display Controller.

The key is that it will call your table view data source & delegate methods, but pass you its table view as the first parameter.

For example (if you store a reference to your table view in an instance variable named `yourTableView`):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == yourTableView) {
        return [listVehicles count];
    } else { // handle search results table view
        return [filteredListItems count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellValue = nil;

    if (tableView == yourTableView) {
        cellValue = [listVehicles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else { // handle search results table view
        cellValue = [filteredListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"vlCell";

    VehicleListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Cell Created");

    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListCell" owner:nil options:nil];

      for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
          if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[VehicleListCell class]]) {
              cell = (VehicleListCell *)currentObject;
          }
      }

      UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pressRecongnizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellPressed:)];
      pressRecongnizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f;
      [cell addGestureRecognizer:pressRecongnizer];
      [pressRecongnizer release];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

    [[cell ignition] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignition.png"]];
    [[cell direction] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"south.png"]];

    cell.licPlate.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hey gerry3 thanx dude.... getting the search table view as I wanted, thanx for this useful information as tableviews and search bar controllers are mostly used in applications.
I have one more question and it is that the code you have given for my own tableview in search is giving the same result of tableview, but the headers I have used A,B,C and D how can I show them too in my search table view

Comment: To show your headers on the search results table you could try to add a view with your labels as the table header view of the search results table.

Comment: How to do that ... also one more thing please, it is that when I search and the search display table shows the background image in the cell in which it has results, while other cells are without background  , they are while as default.

Comment: To set a header view: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = yourHeaderView;`. You are returning the cells used by the results table view, so I would think they would have your cell backgrounds. I often implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and set the cell background color there.

Comment: Thanx gerry3, you helped me so much bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used search View Controller in my application and implementing this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
if(self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text.length>0) {
    self.isSearching=YES;

    NSString *strSearchText = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *ar=[NSMutableArray array];
    // correctly working ! Thanx for watching video !
    for (int i=0; i<self.arOriginal.count; i++) {
        NSString *strData = [self.arOriginal objectAtIndex:i];
        NSRange rng = [strData rangeOfString:strSearchText options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];
        if(rng.length > 0){
            [ar addObject:strData];
        }
    }
    self.arFiltered=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ar];
} else {
    self.isSearching=NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanx hiren443, but what about the table view issue for search results, how can i resolve it